# How to declare that null is a valid value for a kotlin type using avro

Tags: kotlin, avro, nullable

In summary, I'm creating a project that converts a json to an avro file. Some fields of this json can be null.

In Java the solution is add the annotation @Nullable (org.apache.avro.reflect.Nullable) and that works perfectly. However during the conversion to Kotlin this annotation does not work.

I could easily create the schema manually and allow a null type... but I was thinking something cleaner.

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the annotation on the field in Kotlin? Make sure to use the correct [use-site annotation target](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) otherwise you might annotate the property instead of the underlying field.

Comment: That was the problem Sandi! once I set the annotation on the field, kotlin was able to apply

 @field:Nullable val s: String? = null

Comment: Great, happy to help!